# Meaning of "EVEN FOR SOMEONE"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Read the following conversation:

> A : My mind was telling me to say, "Don't go".
>
> B : What are you thinking?
>
> A : *[continues thinking]....*   Not **even for him**.

There were just two people, A and B. So, Thinking about "even" for emphasis is not in the vicinity. My [research](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/even)
told me that "even" could also mean "Fair". So, we could interpret as "A" wanting to tell him to stay but also feels it as unfair for him.

OR there's something else going on?

Is that an idiom?

Comment: Research **not even for**. If you look up **even** by itself you may be misled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is using "even" when speaking to B to signify an unexpected (by B, or by people in general) thing. A's mind is saying "don't go to him (a third person), even though one might expect me to go to him".

> even adverb [ not gradable ] (EMPHASIS) ​ used to emphasize a
>   comparison **or the unexpected** or extreme characteristic of something:

[Even](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/even)

I would not tell a lie, not even to save my mother from prison (many people might expect me to be willing to tell a lie for that purpose).